# Inserir uilabel ou uibutton em uma imagem

Tags: ios, swift

Gostaria de saber se há um jeito de criar um link em um texto utilizando label ou botão dentro de uma imagem.Para inserir texto em uma imagem basta inserir : campotexto.draw e para inserir label ou botão alguém sabe se tem alguma maneira?Desde  já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade você pode fazer o contrário, adicionando uma imagem em um botão.
1. Adicione um UIButton
2. Vá no attribute inspector do botão
3. Defina a propriedade 'Title' do botão como vazia
4. Na propriedade 'Image', defina sua imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: valeu Wender obrigado pela ajuda!